# Run functions in a loop JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of functions that calls another function. I want to run those group of functions in an infinite loop and can't really come up with a logic.

My code looks like this:

```
<script>

function runAnim(x,y) {
    //animation code
}

runAnim(a,2);
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#a').fadeOut('fast');
}, 3000);

runAnim(b,4);
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#b').fadeOut('fast');
}, 3000);

</script>
```

So I want to run these two 'runAnim' functions in an infinite loop. I tried

```
while(1) {}
```

but this hangs up my browser. I tried implementing setInterval method but don't know how I can do this. If you want I can post the runAnim(x,y) function for more clarity.

Comment: WHY do you want an infinite loop??

Comment: So I have few words whose letters fades in randomly and I feed in those words (a and b) through divs. I want these letters to animate endlessly.

Comment: Why not just call the function within the function itself when it is done with the animation? So when it's done just call the function again.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `runAnim` method to include a call to `runAnim` via `setTimeout` so that you can an infinite loop while ensuring that *maximum stack isn't exceeded*.

```
function runAnim(x,y) {
    //animation code
    if ( y == 2 )
    {
       setTimeout( () => {
           runAnim(x,4);
           $('#a').fadeOut('fast'); //call the fadeout here itself
       }, 3000 );
    }
    else
    {
       setTimeout( () => {
           runAnim(x,2);
           $('#a').fadeOut('fast');
       }, 3000 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an explicit infinite loop, you can just let the functions call the other one over and over again

Here is an example with chaining:

```js
function fadeOutA() {
  $('#b').fadeIn('fast');
  $('#a').fadeOut('fast', fadeOutB);
}

function fadeOutB() {
  $('#a').fadeIn('fast');
  $('#b').fadeOut('fast', fadeOutA);
}

function stop() {
  $('#a, #b').stop();
}


$('#start').click(fadeOutA);

$('#stop').click(stop);
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;

}

#a {
  background-color: green;
}

#b {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>

<button id='start'>START</button>
<button id='stop'>STOP</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

What i suggest is don't write any logic which run is infinite loop, because it will cause problem for your browser. But event if you want it to be done done something like below

create for loop `for(var i=0;;i++){}` and then place your function inside this loop which will execute unlimited times.